# What should I use in angularJS to output a resource's name when I have its ID?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller with $scope.users = [{id: 1, name: "Test"}, {id: 2, name: "Dude"}];

I would like to do something like {{id | getName}} and it would take the id I have, crawl $scope.users to look for the corresponding ID and output "Test" or "Dude" depending on the value of id.

What should I use in angularJS to achieve this ?

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Winner</th>
      <th>Loser</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="match in matchs">
    <tr>
      <!-- What I want is instead of winner_id / loser_id go and get from $scope.users the id and output user name instead -->
      <td>{{match.winner_id}} - {{match.winner_score}}</td>
      <td>{{match.loser_id}} - {{match.loser_score}}</td>
      <td>{{match.created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wHVG6/

Comment: Can you show the view (HMTL) context in which you are trying to render this information? You seem to be approaching this from the wrong angle.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. (Remove the space, SO didn't want me to post it for some reason)

Comment: SO will not let you post fiddle's without including the code.  The reason being is that the fiddle could get removed or modified and then this question is useless.  So include the code in the question as well as posting a fiddle.

Comment: Yoshi, this was the answer. You should post it as one so I can accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without writing your own, use the built-in [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter):

```
{{(users | filter:{id: 1})[0].name}}
```

Your own filter could look something like:

```
app.filter('getName', ['filterFilter', function (filterFilter) {
  return function (input, id) {
    var r = filterFilter(input, {id: id})[0];
    return r && r.name;
  };
}]);
```

with:

```
{{users | getName:2}}
```

Though, mind that the *input* is `users`, not the *id*. This is needed as a filter has no direct scope access, so you'll have to provide every data needed.

Alternatively, you could wrap it in a simple getter function:

```
$scope.getName = function getName(id) {
  return getNameFilter($scope.users, id);
};
```

with:

```
{{getName(3)}}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/exezik/4/

---

full code:

```
(function (app, ng) {
  app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'getNameFilter', function ($scope, getNameFilter) {
    $scope.users = [{id: 1, name: "Test"}, {id: 2, name: "Dude"}, {id: 3, name: "Foobar"}];

    $scope.getName = function getName(id) {
      return getNameFilter($scope.users, id);
    };
  }]);

  app.filter('getName', ['filterFilter', function (filterFilter) {
    return function (input, id) {
      var r = filterFilter(input, { id: id})[0];
      return r && r.name;
    };
  }]);
}(angular.module('Test', []), angular));
```

Comment: {{(users | filter:{id: 1})[0].name}} doesn't work when there are more than ten users. When I try to select the user with an ID of 1 it will select the user with an ID of 11 for some reason.

Comment: @Ping you sure about that? Maybe it's a version thing, though with 1.1.5 I can't reproduce something like you described: http://jsbin.com/exezik/6/